# Create rows equivalent to the number of ID field in particular column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a detailed column in df which can have multiple customer information, as in the first table below.

If the detailed column has more than one customer information, I need to create a new row for every customer, as in the second table.

How can I do this in Python?

| date | time | consumer | details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/11 | 12:00 | abc | ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef, ID: 324,Qty:2,Name: ghiefg, |
| 13/11 | 13:00 | def | ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef, |
| 14/11 | 11:00 | ghj | ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef, ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef, |

| date | time | consumer | details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/11 | 12:00 | abc | ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef, |
| 12/11 | 12.00 | abc | ID: 324,Qty:2,Name: ghiefg |
| 13/11 | 13:00 | def | ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef, |
| 14/11 | 11:00 | ghj | ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef, |
| 14/11 | 11:00 | hgf | ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef, |

Comment: the example data before and after creating new rows don't match.  Are they supposed to match, or am I not seeing a pattern here.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookahead regex to `split` the string, then `explode` it:

```
df['details'] = df['details'].str.split(',\s*(?=ID:)')
df.explode('details')
```

output:

```
    date   time consumer                       details
0  12/11  12:00      abc   ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef
0  12/11  12:00      abc       ID: 324,Qty:2,Name: ghi
1  13/11  13:00      def  ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef,
2  14/11  11:00      ghj   ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef
2  14/11  11:00      ghj      ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are 3 fields (ID, Qty, Name) for each customer you could try something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date:": ["12/11", "13/11", "14/11"],
        "time": ["12:00", "13:00", "11:00"],
        "consumer": ["abc", "def", "ghj"],
        "details": [
            "ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef,ID: 324,Qty:2,Name: ghi",
            "ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef",
            "ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef,ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abc",
        ],
    }
)
df["details"] = df["details"].apply(
    lambda txt: [
        ','.join(txt.split(",")[idx : idx + 3]) for idx in range(0, len(txt.split(",")), 3)
    ]
)

df = df.explode("details").reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

```
Sample Output

   date:   time consumer                      details
0  12/11  12:00      abc  ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef
1  12/11  12:00      abc      ID: 324,Qty:2,Name: ghi
2  13/11  13:00      def  ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef
3  14/11  11:00      ghj  ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abcdef
4  14/11  11:00      ghj     ID:123, Qty: 1,Name: abc
```